# How show content above specific screen size with Boostrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I want to display one div or another on the page depending on the screen size. So I have:

```
<div class="index_1 hidden-xs">
  something
</div>
```

the other one I should do

```
<div class="index_2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  something
</div>
```

Is there another way to make the last one to be more readable?

Something like:

```
<div class="index_2 above-xs">
  something
</div>
```